# Facebook event time: Trouble at 12 pm

Tags: user-interface, facebook-events

Every week I create several Facebook events beginning at 12:00 and finishing at 13:00.

- No problem for the ending time: I just type "13" and Facebook proposes me "1:00 pm" in the drop-down list.
- But the starting time is a huge frustration. If I type "12", this appears:

[image]

12 pm is nowhere to be found. No way to scroll.

The only solution I have found is to type manually "12:00 p", paying special attention to have the same spacing as them.
Have I missed something? Is there an easier way?
Or is it just another example of a very counter-intuitive user interface?

Answer (score 3):

<del>That’s strange. I get 12:00 pm and if I want to insert 12:00 am, I enter 00: and it gives me the list you are seeing—12:00 am. So it might very well be some kind of bug, or it could have something to do with the moment of the day when you are making the event. (Pure speculation since I can’t reproduce your situation.)</del>

**Update:** it depends on the moment of the day when you are *creating* the event. So, if your current time is somewhere within `00:00` to `12:00 pm`, by entering `12:` you will get the `pm` suggestions list. If your current time is somewhere within `12:00 pm` to midnight, you will get the `am` suggestions list. It’s not dependent on the date of the event but the moment of the day when you are *creating* the event.

Creating an event before 12:00 pm (**at the moment of the creation**):

[image]

[image]

Creating an event after 12:00 pm (**at the moment of the creation**):

[image]

Comment: Interesting thanks! It is reproducible at pretty much any time of the day. I am at UTC+9 (Tokyo), that might matter? Or maybe it is a browser bug? I can reproduce it on several computers, all running Ubuntu/Chrome.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul, see the update to my initial answer. I’ve just tested it again and I was able to reproduce what you were describing in your question.

Comment: +1 Nice investigation! I was mistaken about "any time of the day", I will retry a morning to just to check. So it seems like a Facebook bug, I guess? UI behavior should not depend on time of day, especially for events that will happen in a few days.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I think it’s more of a tradeoff made to keep the suggestions list short. Whether if is a good or bad decision, I don’t know.